# Jquery scroll function to determine whether div is within viewport not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I am trying to build a function which checks whether a set of divs are within the visible viewport. I have the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $w = $(window);
    var bottom_edge_y = $w.scrollTop()  + $w.height();
    var top_edge_y = $w.scrollTop();

    $('#itin_list').children('div').each(function () {
        var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(),
        divOffset = $('#'+ $(this).attr('id')).offset().top,
        if(top_edge_y < divOffset< bottom_edge_y){
            alert("caught");
        }
    });
)};
```

However this code alerts every time, even if the `divOffset` is not within the range specified in the if condition. What is the issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Suggest you look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport if you haven't already. Lots of good info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with your if condition. You cannot compare 3 numbers in a single comparison like this.

```
Instead of `if(top_edge_y < divOffset< bottom_edge_y),
```

use this:

```
 if(top_edge_y < divOffset &&  divOffset<bottom_edge_y)`
```